# Does IIS7 cache video(mp4/wmv) files?

Tags: caching, iis, iis-7.5

We are building a video application, videos would be stored on the file system of the web-server and contents are being served by IIS7(W2K8).

We would like to improve the performance of the content delivery and cache the video files(as expected that users would be accessing only top 50videos on a daily basis), Does IIS7 cache video(mp4/wmv) files by default?

If not, is there a way to let the IIS7 to cache the video files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, IIS 7.5 will not cache your video files.

To use IIS to improve your performance through caching you can use a feature of IIS called Output Caching, you have a good tutorial [here](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/caching), on how to set it up!

When performing the setup for your video file extensions, you will face the dilema, of whether to choose Kernel mode or User mode for caching. When you get there I suggest you read [this](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/windows-kernel-cache) first to make your final decision. Only who can decide whether to use one mode or the other, due to their tradeoffs, quickly speaking, on one side kernel mode is faster but is more limited, and user mode is slower but doesn't have so many limitations.